# MIN / MAX functions in Spring Data JPA with Amazon Aurora DB ( greatest-n-per-group Query)

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, greatest-n-per-group

I have this query spring spring data, I want to know if it is possible in 1 query also the get the updateDate from where the min Price occurs

```
@Query("select min (hp.price) from HotelPrice hp where hp.hotel = ?1 and hp.updateDate > ?2 ")
float getMinPrice (Hotel hotel, Date date);
```

Comment: From an SQL point of view, this is a trivial [tag:greatest-n-per-group] query, which depends on your RDBMS.  From a spring point of view, you could probably do something like `SomeCustomType getFirstCustomTypeByHotelIdAndUpdateDateGreaterThanOrderByPriceDesc(Integer hotelId, LocalDate date)` (something similar seems to work for me - no clue if you can use the complete POJO on the query), where `SomeCustomType` has a `BigDecimal` price field (don't use binary floating point for monetary types, things get strange) and a `LocalDate` update field (forget java.util.Date exists, please).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  hp.price, 
        hp.updateDate
    FROM  HotelPrice AS hp
    WHERE  hp.hotel = ?1
      AND  hp.updateDate > ?2 
    ORDER BY hp.price ASC
    LIMIT 1
```

(I'll leave it up to you to run that in a Spring context.)

This is actually simpler than "greatest-n-per-group", or even "groupwise max".  Simply order the output (`ORDER BY`) and pick off the first row (`LIMIT 1`).